# Filter menu parent dropdown by language for multilingual site?

Tags: 7, routes, i18n-l10n

I am working on a multilingual site that has about 60+ pages per language. When an admin user wants to add a page to the navigation menu its becoming quite the task because literally every single link (from all languages) is listed in Main Menu. Its even more confusing because the site has some cases where French and German are in the menu twice because the site has Canada-French and France-French as a language.

Is there any way to manage the navigation menu better? Like if I select German for the language could the menu dropdown automatically filter itself to just show the German nav items? Right now we have a list of about 300+ items in the dropdown :(

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_editor (menu_editor) does not actually filters but help a bit on managing menus

Comment: Enable the i18_menu module, which is part of the i18n project, and set the configuration in the menu edit page.

Comment: I have that enabled but I'm not seeing how it actually helps in this situation. When I create a node and go to the 'Menu settings' section every single menu item is listed in the dropdown for all languages.

Comment: Did you check out the "Menu per language" module: https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n_menu_overview ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the issue page for this problem: https://www.drupal.org/node/1242288. There are patches but as Jose Reyero points out, it would be only a partial solution.

There is a https://www.drupal.org/project/content_menu which enables you to first deal with the menu and then with the content instead of vice versa. Haven't tried but seems nice. This combined with Fixed language menus (provided by Menu Translation at admin/structure/menu/manage/menu-mymenu/edit, Multilingual options - Translation mode) could clean up the menu interface nicely.

Personally, I usually just don't bother dealing with the Parent item, I just head to the menu interface after creating a node, and drag my item, which will be at the bottom, to its place.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Entity translation which has a submodule called Entity Translation Menu to achieve the desired menu. On the menu itself you need to select:

"Translate and Localize. Menu items with language will allow translations. Menu items without language will be localised."

Instead of having different links for different languages you can then create a menu link in one language and translate it into another language.

Answer (score -1):

Enable the [Multilingual Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module. The very same thing had happened to me years ago.